# Is there a benefit of putting headings in the tab order?

Tags: screen-reader, tabindex

Question about navigation through headings of web-applications on screen readers.

Is there a benefit of putting headings in the tab order (by adding tabindex="0" to all H tags) or the standard ways of going through headings provided by screen readers (for example by pressing H) are good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your headings correctly, screen readers will move to them correctly, also screen readers are set for the user, depending on locale, so you should not attempt to force the flow of the document by overriding the natural flow of the elements.